# How to connect my application with MySQL enterprise database image deployed on a VM instance on oracle cloud infrastructure?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I want to connect my web application which is in development phase to the MySQL database image deployed on a VM in the oracle cloud infrastructure. Currently, I have been able to deploy the MySQL database image on the VM instance and I am able to connect to it through the CLI as well as from Workbench installed on my remote pc and create and query databases from the CLI. The database changes (new db, table creation, updation) are represented in the Workbench as well as any other remote environment that I use to connect to the VM.

So I believe the database has been correctly deployed.
The problem that I am facing right now when I try to connect to the MySQL DB from within any of my applications is that I get some connection timeout error and I am not able to connect to it from within my code. I am new to this and I am not able to understand the reason behind this. I have spent quite a few days to figure out the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Sequelize ORM and mysql2

Below is my config.json file for connecting with the remotely deployed database:

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "root",
   "host": "193.122.62.76",
  "dialect": "mysql",
    "password": "*****",
    "database": "test"
  }
```

Server.js file for setting up the server

```
const express=require('express')

const app=express()

app.use(express.json()) 
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}))

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  next();
});

var models=require('./models')

models.sequelize.sync().then(function(){
    console.log('Database looks fine')
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err,'Something went wrong with the db')
})

require('./routers/index')(app)
port=process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(port,console.log('server up'))
```

index.js file in models:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

The connection timeout error that I get:

```
ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at ConnectionManager.connect (D:\Notes\Node\servertest\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\connection-manager.js:126:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async ConnectionManager._connect (D:\Notes\Node\servertest\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:318:24)
    at async D:\Notes\Node\servertest\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:250:32
    at async ConnectionManager.getConnection (D:\Notes\Node\servertest\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:280:7)
    at async D:\Notes\Node\servertest\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:613:26
    at async MySQLQueryInterface.createTable (D:\Notes\Node\servertest\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:225:12)
    at async Function.sync (D:\Notes\Node\servertest\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1300:5)
    at async Sequelize.sync (D:\Notes\Node\servertest\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:793:35) {
  parent: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
      at Connection._handleTimeoutError (D:\Notes\Node\servertest\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:178:17)
      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
      at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {
    errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    syscall: 'connect',
    fatal: true
  },
  original: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
      at Connection._handleTimeoutError (D:\Notes\Node\servertest\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:178:17)
      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
      at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {
    errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    syscall: 'connect',
    fatal: true
  }
} Something went wrong with the db
```

Comment: Did you add an ingress rule in your security list to allow the CIDR of your app to connect to port 3306? Some info here : https://www.ateam-oracle.com/oci-network-security-groups-vs-security-lists

Answer (score 1):

The timeout error is typically caused by not being able to establish a connection to the server. Make sure that your mysql server is running where you are trying to connect to, as well as making sure the host ip/port entered are correct. Also important to verify that the firewall is configured to allow access.

Connecting will also require proper policy in place to allow user access which I am guessing you do have but can't hurt to verify. You can review connecting to a DB system using OCI here - https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Database/Tasks/connectingDB.htm